# View.getTranslationX/Y() Equivalent?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am currently working on a small project and require assistance (obviously). The project itself involves me creating a standalone app out of the JellyBean BeanBag easteregg and have succeeded in doing so however I also want to create and maintain compatibility with the 2.3 sdk and have also managed to do so using the NineOldAndroids Library. The 2.3 API does not support the methods setScaleX() or setScaleY() so I made the following changes:

from

```
            final float scale = lerp(MIN_SCALE,MAX_SCALE,z);
            setScaleX(scale); setScaleY(scale);
```

to

```
            final float scale = lerp(MIN_SCALE,MAX_SCALE,z);
            ViewHelper.setScaleX(v,scale); ViewHelper.setScaleY(v,scale);
```

the issue comes from the ViewHelper setScale requiring a View argument as opposed to the normal call requiring only a float value.  I have tried using

```
            for (int i=0; i<getChildCount(); i++) {
                View v = getChildAt(i);
                ViewHelper.setScaleX(v,scale); ViewHelper.setScaleY(v,scale);
            }
```

But this gives the result of each childview being set to the exact same scale at the same time while the original method sets each individual view to a unique scale. Any ideas as to how I can achieve the same effect? The full source may be viewed [here](https://github.com/jetx2x/BeanBag/tree/WIP) if I left out any necessary information.

EDIT: Fixed by using:

```
    static Random sRNG = new Random();
    static float MIN_SCALE = 0.2f;
    static float MAX_SCALE = 1f;

    static float lerp(float a, float b, float f) {
        return (b-a)*f + a;
    }

    static float randfrange(float a, float b) {
        return lerp(a, b, sRNG.nextFloat());
    }

            for (int i=0; i<getChildCount(); i++ ) {
                View v = getChildAt(i);
                float scale = randfrange(MIN_SCALE,MAX_SCALE);
                ViewHelper.setScaleX(v,scale); ViewHelper.setScaleY(v,scale);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only initializing `scale` one time. Why would you expect it to be different for each one in the loop? Move your `scale` initialization into the loop.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and still receive the same result, could you provide an example of what you mean? Simply moving it into the loop did not solve it

Comment: Did you log the value of `scale` for each initialization? This should be trivial. If the `scale` values are the same, then of course they will all be the same scale.

Comment: Your suggestion led me in the right direction and eventually solved the issue